# JQuery plugin form - how to submit form using onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JQuery - I need to use the JQuery form plugin for a file upload but I would like to submit the form as soon as the file is selected (onchange event of the the input tag:myfile, as shown below),

```
<html>
<body>
    <form encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="file-echo.php" encoding="multipart/form-data" id='fileUploadForm'>
        **<input name="myfile" type="file">**
        <input value="Upload File to Server" type="submit">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div style="width: 0%;" class="bar"></div>
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
    </div>

    <div id="status"><br></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I copied the following sample JS code from plugin website but I would like to adapt it so that the form is submitted upon selecting the file.  Any pointers please ?  thanks in advance.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#myfile').change(function(){

         // alert("");
       $('#fileUploadForm').ajaxForm({ 
            beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
            success: SubmitSuccesful,
            error: AjaxError                               
          });

       });

      function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
          var queryString = $.param(formData);
          alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
          return true;
        }

        function AjaxError() {
          alert("An AJAX error occured.");
        }

        function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {        
          alert("SuccesMethod:\n\n" + responseText);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If it works at all (since the file upload object is fickle due to security concerns) AND you mean to SUBMIT the form as stated in the original question - then this could work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myfile').change(function(){
       $('#fileUploadForm').submit();
     });
 });
```

If you want to Ajax the data, then try adding some brackets you seem to have been missing

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myfile').change(function(){

     // alert("");
      $('#fileUploadForm').ajaxForm({ 
        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: SubmitSuccesful,
        error: AjaxError                               
      });

   });
}); // close the .ready
```

Comment: thanks for the response mplungjan: actually I forgot to mention that the bit on the onchange method was modified by me - and that doesnt work as you probably did figure out. I amended the code to what you provided and the form is submitted indeed. However, this is no longer using the plugin submit functionality is it ?  The reason why i need to use this is because it takes care of the multipart/form-data ..... also I would like to use the beforeSubmit, and callback functionality as used in the example ..

Comment: Ah, then please change the words "submit the form" to "upload the file with Ajax" since that is what you want